# How to loop & scraping data for multiple pages using python and beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup

I have to iterate over 4000 pages: after each page. When we have arrived on the last page available, there are no more pages, so we are done and can exit the loop with e.g. last.

There might not be a database covering all countries of Europe (for instance the non-democratic country Belarus does not publish much information). So if you need more data that OpenStreetMap has, you will probably need to go country-by-country. Below is the data for France. The French government has created a website showing the list of all 4307 hospitals and clinics in France:

http://www.ScopeSante.fr

Click on "Voir la liste des établissements" to get the full list. at a first glance the issue about scraping from page to page - can be solved via different approaches:

See the numbers that seem to count from zero to maximum - and in between we have the bunch of numbers that have sites to fetch ; eg 470000027

We have no pagination on the bottom of the page: see for example:

```
https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/470000027/fiche-detaillee/" LINIQUE ESQUIROL-SAINT-HILAIRE</span></a>
https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/470005406/fiche-detaillee/" CH AGEN NERAC - HOPITAL DE MONBRAN-(Modification juridique le 31 décembre 2016)</span></a>
https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/470008780/fiche-detaillee/" EHPAD-USLD DE POMPEYRIE CH AGEN NERAC</span></a>
https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/470000423/fiche-detaillee/" CH AGEN NERAC - HOPITAL SAINT-ESPRIT</span></a>
https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/470000159/fiche-detaillee/" CLINIQUE CALABET</span></a>
https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/040780405/fiche-detaillee/" CENTRE DES CARMES</span></a>
https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/430000166/fiche-detaillee/" CENTRE SSR JALAVOUX</span></a>
https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/050000223/fiche-detaillee/" CENTRE HOSPITALIER AIGUILLES QUEYRAS</span></a>
https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/030000160/fiche-detaillee/" CENTRE HOSPITALIER SPECIALISE D'AINAY</span></a>
https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/950500017/fiche-detaillee/" GHI DU VEXIN SSR SITE AINCOURT</span></a>
https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/400782769/fiche-detaillee/" POLYCLINIQUE DE L'ADOUR</span></a>
https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/400780367/fiche-detaillee/" CLINIQUE MEDICALE JEAN SARRAILH</span></a>
```

and so forth and so forth.. well we can set this url (s) as a base -

if we have an array from which we load the urls that need to be visited - we would come across all the pages..
we have records on approx 4400 Pages that we have to visit.

Regarding the **loop-process:**

Additional info after page parameter here

this means you can read the content of the page, then change the value of page by 1, and read the the next page.... and so on.

```
import csv
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for i in range(4400):      # Number of pages plus one 
    url = "".format(i)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

    # Your code for each individual page here 

  html = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    Title = soup.find_all ,,,, 
    for i in Title:
        try:

            print(text)
f.close()
```

see below a sheme:

the question is - is the parserprocess allright - with te itteration from zero to 100 000 ?

```
<ul><li class="views-row">
              <div class="views-field views-field-title">
                <div class="field-content">
                  <a href="https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/800002503/fiche-detaillee/" onclick="javascript:_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Accès fiche établissement depuis …', 'Toutes les fiches établissements']);"><span class="ville">ABBEVILLE</span><span class="etablissement">SA CLINIQUE SAINTE ISABELLE</span></a>
                  <div class="clear_left"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li><li class="views-row">
              <div class="views-field views-field-title">
                <div class="field-content">
                  <a href="https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/800006231/fiche-detaillee/" onclick="javascript:_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Accès fiche établissement depuis …', 'Toutes les fiches établissements']);"><span class="ville">ABBEVILLE</span><span class="etablissement">SSR CH ABBEVILLE</span></a>
                  <div class="clear_left"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li><li class="views-row">
              <div class="views-field views-field-title">
                <div class="field-content">
                  <a href="https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/800015539/fiche-detaillee/" onclick="javascript:_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Accès fiche établissement depuis …', 'Toutes les fiches établissements']);"><span class="ville">ABBEVILLE</span><span class="etablissement">HAD CH ABBEVILLE</span></a>
                  <div class="clear_left"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li><li class="views-row">
              <div class="views-field views-field-title">
                <div class="field-content">
                  <a href="https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/800000143/fiche-detaillee/" onclick="javascript:_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Accès fiche établissement depuis …', 'Toutes les fiches établissements']);"><span class="ville">ABBEVILLE</span><span class="etablissement">CH ABBEVILLE</span></a>
                  <div class="clear_left"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li><li class="views-row">
              <div class="views-field views-field-title">
                <div class="field-content">
                  <a href="https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/570000380/fiche-detaillee/" onclick="javascript:_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Accès fiche établissement depuis …', 'Toutes les fiches établissements']);"><span class="ville">ABRESCHVILLER</span><span class="etablissement">ABRESCHVILLER - CRS SAINT LUC</span></a>
                  <div class="clear_left"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li><li class="views-row">
              <div class="views-field views-field-title">
                <div class="field-content">
                  <a href="https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/340017292/fiche-detaillee/" onclick="javascript:_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Accès fiche établissement depuis …', 'Toutes les fiches établissements']);"><span class="ville">AGDE</span><span class="etablissement">UADSA ST GUILHEM PAYS D'AGDE</span></a>
                  <div class="clear_left"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li><li class="views-row">
              <div class="views-field views-field-title">
                <div class="field-content">
                  <a href="https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/340780436/fiche-detaillee/" onclick="javascript:_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Accès fiche établissement depuis …', 'Toutes les fiches établissements']);"><span class="ville">AGDE</span><span class="etablissement">HOPITAL ST LOUP HBT AGDE</span></a>
                  <div class="clear_left"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li><li class="views-row">
              <div class="views-field views-field-title">
```

the question is - is the parserprocess allright - with te itteration from zero to 100 000 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I visited the list of all establishments web page, I saw that the site uses its own private API to get the list of establishments in the first place. Check out:

https://ws.scopesante.fr/v4/carte-etablissements

The private API returns the full list of establishments along with their "id" numbers in JSON format. So, there you go. This *is* the full list. You can use the "id" number of each organization to look up the "details" page for each organization. So, using the route to the "details" page:

https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/PUT_ID_NUMBER_HERE/fiche-detaillee/

You can just grab all the "id" numbers, put them in a Python list, and then iterate over *that* list (as oppose to trying to count up as you had described above).

Note: Please be respectful when scraping this data. Making ~4000 requests to the server in a short amount of time would increase load. Also, if this site has anti-bot mechanisms in place, you may be blocked.

You were right. There are about 4400 establishments; specifically, I am seeing 3869 establishments. But, you have access to see the "id" number for each organization. So, it is more efficient to use these "id" numbers when you scrape the website.

EDIT: I was messing with the API even more and found that you can get the details for a specific establishment directly by calling the API. See:

https://ws.scopesante.fr/v4/fiche-identite/010000024

This returns the details on the specific establishment. Just replace the number on the end of the URL with the "id" number of the establishment you are looking up.

Using an API is usually more efficient than scraping the pages directly. Using the API also has less load on the server as compared to scraping web pages. The API gives you the data directly. Web pages give you the data *and* a bunch of resources (CSS, JS, etc.) that you don't need to see.

Comment: hello dear coltoneakins - many thanks. That sounds great. One Question though: does this mean that i can get each detail page by requestion a certain url https://ws.scopesante.fr/v4/fiche-identite/010000024 etc etx. Is there a range from 1 to x corresponding to the number that is at the end of the URL - eg 010000024 or 1 ..... or 010000024 plus 1  and 010000024 plus 2 - love to hear from you